# Style for VS Solution Explorer TreeView

Tags: wpf, treeview

I would like to implement a treeview control in a WPF app that has similar look and feel as the TreeView in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer.

I've heard Visual Studio was developed with WPF.

I'm assuming Microsoft used System.Windows.Controls.TreeView for Solution Explorer.

*How can I style my TreeView so that it looks and behaves like the one in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer?*

**Update**

As Ed suggested, I used Snoop to determine that VS uses the `SolutionPivotTreeView`. I guess it's not opensource. I wish I could find something more actively maintained than TreeViewEx.

Comment: I would not make that assumption about the Solution Explorer. I might fire up Snoop and try to find out. Either way, this is not a suitable question for StackOverflow. There isn't a boolean property named TreeView.IsLikeVisualStudioTreeView. The answer is going to be hundreds of lines of XAML and C# code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is asking for an implementation of a poorly-specified set of features, not a solution to a specific programming problem.

Comment: @EdPlunkett thanks for the tip on Snoop - definitely a cool tool.  Snoop smells no dogfood though, will update question.

Comment: I just googled SolutionPivotTreeView and found some interesting results. It must in a DLL somewhere, you know.